# A precise definition for a sequence of functions that "Converge Pointwise, but not Uniformly"

Tags: definition, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am trying to lay down a precise deifinition of "Pointwise Convergent but NOT Uniformly Convergent" sequence of functions $(f_n)$ with domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$.

We denote $D \setminus S(\epsilon, k) = T $, and $f(x)$ be the limit function of the sequence. $S( \epsilon, k)$ denotes a set dependent on $\epsilon$ and $k$.

Here is the definition:

$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\ \exists$ a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and a maximal set $S( \epsilon, k)$, such that $|f_n (x) -f(x)| < \epsilon$, $\ \forall n \geq k$, $\ \forall x \in S$, with $T \neq \emptyset$ for any finite $k $ but $T \to \emptyset$ as $k \to \infty$.

Is this definition rigorous? Or does it have any flaws which I am missing?

Comment: What is a "maximal set"?

Comment: @kccu , The largest possible set $S$, such that $k$ does not fail.

Comment: What makes one set "higher" than another?

Comment: "larger" or "higher"? I edited that term to "largest"

Comment: And what do you mean by $T \to \emptyset$ as $k \to \infty$? You said there exists $k$, so what does it mean to take $k$ to infinity?

Comment: @kccu, exactly the weakest point. It doesn't make much sense to write it that way.

Comment: I would like to improve the definition. But there must be some way to replace the $T \to \emptyset$ part with something far better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92856/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-kccu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of pointwise convergence is:

> For every $x \in D$, and for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n  \geq N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

The definition of uniform convergence is:

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq N$ and every $x \in D$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, the definition of *not* converging uniformly is:

> There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist $n \geq N$ and $x \in D$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$.

So finally, the definition of pointwise convergence without uniform convergence is:

> For every $x \in D$, and every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. However, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N  \in\mathbb{N}$, there exist $n \geq N$ and $x \in D$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$.

Now what you are trying to do is say for a given $\epsilon$, some $x$'s will have the same value of $N$ "work". So define
$$S(N,\epsilon) = \{x \in D : \text{for all } n \geq N, |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\}.$$
We know by the definition of pointwise convergence that for every $x \in D$ and every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $x \in S(N,\epsilon)$. Moreover, it's clear that $S(N_1,\epsilon) \subseteq S(N_2,\epsilon)$ if $N_1<N_2$. So we can say the $S(N,\epsilon)$'s are **increasing to $D$**, meaning 
$$S(1,\epsilon) \subseteq S(2,\epsilon) \subseteq S(3,\epsilon) \subseteq \cdots \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty S(N,\epsilon)=D.$$
This is equivalent to saying the sets $T(N,\epsilon):=D\setminus S(N,\epsilon)$ are decreasing to $\emptyset$, meaning
$$T(1,\epsilon) \supseteq T(2,\epsilon) \supseteq T(3,\epsilon) \supseteq \cdots \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty T(N,\epsilon) = \emptyset.$$

Now the definition of pointwise convergence can be phrased as:

> For every $\epsilon>0$, the sets $S(N,\epsilon)$ defined above are increasing to $D$ as $N \to \infty$.

However, this says nothing about not converging uniformly. To phrase this in terms of the $S(N,\epsilon)$'s we can write:

> There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x \notin S(N,\epsilon)$ (i.e., $S(N,\epsilon) \neq D$).

So finally, the definition of pointwise convergence without uniform convergence, in terms of the $S(N,\epsilon)$'s, is:

> For every $\epsilon >0$, the sets $S(N,\epsilon)$ increase to $D$ as $N \to \infty$, but there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that none of the sets $S(N,\epsilon)$ are equal to $D$.

Note that we can't say "for all $\epsilon >0$, and all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $S(N,\epsilon) \neq D$." That is too strong, since it is completely possible that for some $\epsilon$ (say $\epsilon = 1000000$), all of the $S(N,\epsilon)$ are equal to $D$. This would happen if, for instance, all of the functions have codomain $[0,1000000]$. All that is required for uniform convergence to fail is that there exists *some* epsilon so that the same $N$ will not work for every $x$.

Comment: I also came up with something very similar to that of your answer. (by negating quantifiers). But I wanted to omit this

However, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N  \in\mathbb{N}$, there exist $n \geq N$ and $x \in D$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$.

with something better. The intuition behind my $\to \emptyset $ was that at any stage of $N$, there are always some more points for which epsilon inequality fails. So, only when $N$ is infinitely large, we can find no more such anomaly.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas See my last edit. It is not true that for every $\epsilon$ and $N$ there are always some points for which the inequality fails.

Comment: Regarding your last statement, I interpret it as:

Large values of epsilon are not efficient bounds. So, although we can include the entirety of $D$, we miss out the points where some $N$ works and where doesn't

Comment: Please correct me if I did not get it.

Comment: A very well written answer indeed.

Comment: Yes, that is more or less the idea.